# Scala, error on * (asterisk) char using scala.sys.process

Tags: scala, command

I'm trying to run a command from Scala

```
val cmd = "scp -r /path/to/dir/* user@ip:target/dir"
print(cmd)    
cmd.!!
```

if I copy the command inside the terminal it works without problem, but running it using the .!! method I obtain

```
/path/to/dir/*: No such file or directory
```

What could be the problem? thanks

Comment: bash expands `*` for you before executing command. try executing your command with bash

Answer (score 1):

Asterisk is expanded by `bash`, so you'll need to get `bash` to execute the command for you, can be done like this:

```
val cmd = "echo \"scp -r /path/to/dir/* user@ip:target/dir\" | bash"
print(cmd)    
cmd.!!
```

Comment: Be very careful how you construct the string you pass to bash here. There is potential for some nasty injection attacks. E.g. if you got the path from the user, and they embedded <backtick>rm -rf ~<backtick> in that path name...

Comment: I continue to have the same problem, | operator works inside the terminal, but it's not recognised running it with !!,  so running the code that you had proposed I obtain - ( "scp -r /path/to/dir/* user@ip:target/dir\" | bash ) - it's printing all the string following the echo command